# Laravel datetime created_at

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question. If created_at in my database is datetime and I want to make a query like this

```
whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
```

I get nothing as a result. How can i handle this situation ?

Another case: I want

```
 whereDate('created_at', '=', date('M'))
```

Comment: What dbms do you use?

Comment: @HarunYılmaz mysql

Comment: You can use `$q->whereMonth('created_at', '=', date('m'));` if you want the month

Comment: If you're on Laravel 5.6 or later, `whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())`

Comment: Your first case seems to be working as expected for me on my data. Can you be more specific on what kind of data you have that should be selected and is not being selected?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL, you could use `whereRaw`:

```
whereRaw('created_at = CURDATE()')
```

For your second case:

```
whereRaw("month_name = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%b')")
```

Comment: I get this error Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: @alphal Then it probably means that there is more than one table in your query, and that more than one table has a `created_at` column.  The way to fix this is to use an alias to resolve which `created_at` column you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other helper functions maybe:

```
$query->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))
      ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', date('m'))
      ->whereDay('created_at', '=', date('d'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First Query: You can use `Carbon` specifying date format (date without time `toDateString()`  / date with time `toDateTimeString()` ).

```
$query->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateTimeString());
```

Second Query: Just query on `whereMonth`

```
$query->whereMonth('created_at', '=', date('m'));
```